# Something is wrong with my model SQLAlchemy SQlite Flask Python

Tags: python, sqlite, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

There's something wrong with my model? do you se any anomaly? Trying to store a user and password to SQLite db with SQLAlchemy but returns an error saying the column pwd in the user table doesn't exist, indeed if I check sqlite> .schema it returns the table with the correct structure and pwd column, no data inside if I query though.

I firstly create the table with Table() function, then under I define the User class, maybe is because in the class there are no references to the column names of the table? but I have imported **tablename**="user" so it should work no?

```
from flask import Flask 
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_bcrypt import Bcrypt
from sqlalchemy import *

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///data-users.sqlite'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class User(db.Model):
    
    id = db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key = True, autoincrement=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(64), unique = True)
    pwd = db.Column(db.String())

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<User %r>' % self.username
```

Here I store the user data in the table

```
        from store_user_db import User, db

        db.create_all()

        DICP_FTP_DESTINATION_PSW=self.submit_pwd()

        user = User(id=001,username="ita_itf",pwd=DICP_FTP_DESTINATION_PSW)
        db.session.add(user)
        db.session.commit()
```

This is the error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError

OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) table user has no column named pwd
[SQL: INSERT INTO user (id, username, pwd) VALUES (?, ?, ?)]
[parameters: (1, 'ita_itf', <read-only buffer for 0x7efe495709f0, size -1, offset 0 at 0x7efe500c3830>)]
```

Comment: maybe instead of referring to db I should refer to the table name? like userstable.Column(...) instead of db.Column(...) ??

Answer (score 0):

The `db.create_all()` will only create tables if they don't already exist.  I suspect that your issue is that you created the table in the recent past, at a point where you didn't yet have the `pwd` column in your model.

So now you run `db.create_all()` and it essentially does nothing (as the `user` table already exists) but falls over when you try to access the never created `pwd` column.

You can `db.drop_all()` to destroy all the current tables, or you could manually (or using a migration tool) add the 'missing' `pwd` column so the database matches the model.

Also, all this code doesn't do anything in this particular example (unless you're doing something unusual in code you haven't included).

```py
engine= create_engine(app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'])

#CREATE TABLE
meta=MetaData()
userstable = Table('user', meta, \
    Column('id', Integer, primary_key = True, autoincrement=True), \
    Column('username', String, unique = True), \
    Column('pwd', LargeBinary,unique = True))
meta.create_all(engine)
```

#### Example Working Version

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_bcrypt import Bcrypt

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = "sqlite:///example.sqlite3"

bcrypt = Bcrypt(app)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)


class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "user"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(64), unique=True)
    pwd = db.Column(db.LargeBinary(), unique=True)

    def __init__(self, id, username, pwd):
        self.id = id
        self.username = username
        self.pwd = bcrypt.generate_password_hash(pwd)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    db.drop_all()  # destroy all the tables.
    db.create_all()  # create all fresh new tables.
    u = User(1, "static", "password")
    db.session.add(u)
    db.session.commit()

    u = User.query.first()  # check out data got stored.
    print(u.pwd)
```

Comment: I get your point and I have removed db.create_all(), I have drop the table user in sqlite, double checked and no table there. then I run my application again and it creates the correct table with pwd column, I check that in sqlite>.schema , and pwd  it's there, but still returns the following error

Comment: OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) table user has no column named pwd

Comment: I have also tried starting a brand new db, so there was no table there before, same issue, I think there is something wrong when it tries to store the password in it. The table seems to be correctly created.

Comment: maybe when I try to store the password I use db.session.add(user), but when I create the table indeed there's no reference to db. Could be that? is not referencing to the table is suppose to?

Comment: If you change `app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///data-users2.sqlite'` to `app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///data-users2.sqlite3'` does the same problem persist? (I wonder if you're deleting/dropping the wrong SQLlite table)

Comment: but the db file is a .sqlite should I rename the db filename?

Comment: the filename extension doesn't really matter in this instance.  I'm just suggesting changing the filename in the python code, so you can be assured you're working on a fresh, new sqlite database.  Don't change the actual filename in the folder.

Comment: even if I start a new db and run the application the error is the same, no idea

Comment: Here's explained pretty well, seems so simple but in this way it won't create any table in my db!   check this link:   flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/quickstart

Comment: if I just do it the way they say in the article it won't even create my db file!

Comment: I've posted an update to my answer, with a confirmed working version of your code-- as you can see, you're on the right track, there's nothing fundamentally wrong with what you're doing-- so if the problem isn't a confusion with the location of the sqlite database, the problem must exist in some extra code you haven't included.

Comment: I see thanks, I have read some more documentation so one important thing to consider is that I'm using Flask-SQLAlchemy and not just sqlalchemy, so I have updated the code in my post here, simplified as per Flask-SQLAlchemy documentation. In this way it should work perfectly, the only issue now is that is not creating the db file, I tried renaming it to a new sqlite db path, but it won't create the db, I think maybe I should add the engine function but not sure where I have to pass it in the code

Comment: SQLALchemy documentation: https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/quickstart/

Comment: My working example also uses Flask-SQLAlchemy, does it work for you?  You can try giving the sqlite database location an absolute location, if you're on OSX that might be something like: `app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = "sqlite:////Users/marcello/Desktop/example.sqlite"` you can refer to https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/engines.html#sqlite for other operating systems.

Comment: IT worked! it didn't show any error and printed out the user, but somehow I cannot see the file "sqlite:///data-users2.sqlite" in the folder, like it wasn't created, and if I check sqlite> .tables  in this one with linux command prompt it wont show any

Comment: anyway it works! I printed the result in the application, doesn't matter where the sqlite file is, thanks a lot! that db.drop_all() was the solution!!

Comment: I just have another problem now, it seems that bcrypt it hashes the password it doesn't encrypt it, which is different, it seems that password hashing cannot be recovered to the original password, I would basically need to decrypt it, because this is an FTP password, has to be decrypted before FTPing the file. How do I do that? it seems that password hash cannot be the solution